# While Loop Won't Run With Nested Elif Statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am still newish to programming and I'm just developing simple programs to automate routine office work.

I have the most barebones code written but whenever I try to add a while loop it breaks the code and causes the program to close after I enter a value for Y. The print text after entering the Y value never appears. I have my code listed below.

Everything works fine until I try to throw it into a while loop, then it stops working. Is there something I am missing here?

Removing the while loop and having everything work again

```
import os
import subprocess
import time
import pyautogui

x=15
y=10
while x != 333:
    print("test")
    print("15 - 10 is",x-y)
    print("Okay now tell me what X should be")
    x = input("Enter a numerical value for X: ")
    print("Excellent! Now let's do Y")
    y = input("Enter a numerical value for Y: ")
    print("Okay now let's compare X and Y")
    #don't forget to indent!
    if x > y:
        print("X is greater than Y!")
    elif y > x:
        print("Y is greater than X!")
    else:
        print("X is equal to Y!")
    print(x, y)
time.sleep(2)
input("Press Enter to continue...")
```

Comment: What do "throw it into a while loop" and "it stops working" mean?

Comment: Its likely throwing a traceback. If you're using a dedicated IDE, look in the console window and see what it prints when it reaches the while loop. If youre opening the file directly, run it via the command line and see what it prints there.

Comment: If I take the exact same working code and embed it into a while loop the program starts crashing after I enter the Y value. Remove the while loop and everything works again.

Comment: `input` returns a string

Comment: ok so it finishes one round in command line then starts again, prints 'test' then gives a traceback (most recent call last): saying line 10, in <module> print("15 - 10 is",x-y) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

what does this mean?

Comment: Oh okay, I think Scott gave me what I needed. How do I get integer values from input rather than strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input` returns a string, so when the loop comes back around and tries to print `x-y`, it crashes because you can't substract strings.

Comment: How can I get a integer return for a value from input given from the user?

Comment: Try using `int(x)`.

Comment: not sure if there was a better way but i added an extra line beneath each input line to convert it into integer using int(), not the most elegant but it works, thanks!